# MOXY does not add namespace prefix in JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I created a DTO class that has a Map. I am processing this map using a custom XMLAdapter:

```
public class CmisObject {

    public CmisObject() {
        this.properties = new HashMap<String, CmisProperty>();
        this.links = new ArrayList<String>();;
    }

    /* Here we override the default HashMap marshalling by Moxy */
    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CmisPropertyMapAdapter.class) 
    private HashMap<String, CmisProperty> properties;
....
```

The adapter is defined like this:

```
   @Override
    public Element marshal(Map<String, CmisProperty> map) throws Exception {

        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("properties");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        for(Entry<String,CmisProperty> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Element childElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.foo.com/bar/cmis", entry.getKey());
            CmisProperty cp = entry.getValue();

            childElement.setAttribute("id", cp.getId());
            childElement.setAttribute("localName", cp.getLocalName());
            ...
            rootElement.appendChild(childElement);
        }
        return rootElement;        
....
```

and, finally I have package-info.java in the package where my DTO class is defined:

```
@XmlSchema(
namespace="http://www.foo.com/bar/baz",
xmlns = {
    @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.foo.com/bar/cmis", prefix = "cmis")
},
elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package com.foo.bar.beans;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Everything works as desired, I am getting a nice JSON, however, no "cmis" prefixes are added.

When I registered the prefix mapping in my application:

```
...
        final Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://www.foo.com/bar/cmis", "cmis"); 

        final MoxyJsonConfig moxyJsonConfig = new MoxyJsonConfig() 
            .setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper) 
            .setNamespaceSeparator(':'); 

        final ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> jsonConfigResolver = moxyJsonConfig.resolver();
        register(jsonConfigResolver);
...
```

all needed prefixes were added.

As far as I understand, the registering step is not needed for MOXy if I have package-info.java defined.

What could be the problem here?

Thank you.